# In flutter,I am using http library, but API data is taking time to load on the device

Tags: flutter

In flutter, I am using http library to fetch server data with the help of API, but API data is taking more time to load on the device (Android 9 Pie).
I want to know if there is any better way to load the API data quickly on my device.

Comment: no, there is no faster ways

Comment: maybe you are making too big requests, that can be paginated, or are hitting a slow server?